# Is $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ actually simple?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

It's probably not hard to prove that $\frak{sl}_n\mathbb{R}$ is simple, so that $SL_n\mathbb{R}$ has no nontrivial connected normal subgroups. But do there exist discrete normal subgroups of $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ aside from $\{I, -I\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any normal subgroup $N\subset SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ has $\pi(N)$ normal in $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$, where $\pi$ is the projection map. It's a standard classical result that $PSL_n(k)$ is simple except for $PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_2) = S_3$ and $PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_3) = A_4$. Given that, if $N$ is discrete, then $\pi(N)$ must therefore be $1$; that is, $N$ is trivial or $\{\pm 1\}$.

Comment: Awesome, do you know where I can find the fact about $PSL_n$ ?

Comment: See eg "Classical Groups and Geometric Algebra" by Grove. This result is proved in the beginning of the book.

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen thanks!